# Pass apostrophe from form to template?

Tags: php, forms, symfony1, symfony-1.4

How can I pass an apostrophe in an action or form?

I do have a form in lib/. It looks like this:

```
'input' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('value' => ' \'\' '))
```

I really want to pass the apostrophe. Is it possible? This was `\'` doesn't work. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Gunnar

Comment: Have you tried `'value' => " '' "`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working:

```
'input' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('value' => "&#39; Some text &#39; "))
```

Double quotes are needed!

Thanks again to Randorn and then tokdzwinel!

Gunnar

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
'input' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('value' => ' &apos;&apos; '))
```

or:

```
'input' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('value' => ' &#39;&#39; '))
```